# Multiple iOS apps using same Dropbox API key ever in production?

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

From the Dropbox API doc:

> **Use a single app key for each distinct app**
>
> If you build multiple apps, use one and exactly one key for each app
>   you make. This makes it much easier for us to debug issues when they
>   arise. That said, if you're just building the same app for different
>   platforms (for example, iOS and Android), you can use the same key.

It sounds like multiple-apps-single-key only makes it *harder to debug*. Does anyone successfully deploy multiple iOS apps with a single app key?

Comment: Another downside would be if two apps use the Sync API to create files in the app folder -- they might stomp on each other's files. Then again, it could be a way to share the files between the two apps -- but then, are they truly different apps?

Comment: I am work on something like the Lite/Pro scenario in Greg's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few different scenarios mentioned in the [Dropbox Platform developer guide](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/devguide#great-apps) you're quoting from, and it's a bit unclear which really applies to your question. To enumerate everything:

1. "multiple different apps (on the same platform)" e.g.:

   - MyCoolTaskApp for iOS
   - MyCoolTimerApp for iOS

     In this case, you need to register different apps with the Dropbox API, which means using a different key in each (since they are different logical apps). Also, this way, users will see the different app names when they look at their linked apps list in [their account](https://www.dropbox.com/account/security).
2. "same app for different platforms" e.g.:

   - MyCoolTaskApp for iOS
   - MyCoolTaskApp for Android

     In this case, you shouldn't register multiple apps with the Dropbox API, and you should use the same key in each (since it is the same logical app.)
3. "multiple versions of the same app (on the same platform)" e.g.:

   - MyCoolTaskApp for iOS Lite
   - MyCoolTaskApp for iOS Pro

     In this case, you shouldn't register multiple apps with the Dropbox API, but due to a technical detail there would be a problem with trying to use a single app key in both, as noted under [Can multiple versions of my app (e.g., free and paid) use the same app folder on iOS or Android?](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/support#common-app-folder) in the Dropbox Developer support FAQ. In this case, you should contact [Dropbox Developer support](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/contact) for help with getting this set up correctly.

To answer your question overall though, each of these scenarios above have been successfully deployed by various developers, but you shouldn't deploy multiple different apps with the same key.

Comment: In 2nd case while applying for production from Dropbox App Console we need to select the platform and it allows to select only one platform at a time. How can we select iOS and Android platform for the same app?

Comment: Scenario 3 is a very common one and having to create a ticket to get a common key for variants of the same app is cumbersome. It's also not a very secure way to make sure an api key isn't used by an unauthorized app. There's a reason almost any other cloud API provider uses the signing key on Android to make sure it's the correct app (SHA-1 usually). DropBox, please consider this for the next version of your API.